# How to Check Remaining Quota for Bing Web Search API v5.0

Tags: bing, bing-api

I'm trying to find the way to check remaining monthly quota for Bing Web Search API v5.0 , against my specific Api Key `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

i previously doing this for v2 apis .

I want to know if there's any way to find this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a trial key from microsoft.com/cognitive? If so, you would normally go to your subscriptions page (after you sign in to the site with your Microsoft account) to check your remaining quota: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-US/subscriptions.

Note that unfortunately, at the moment, the show quota functionality is currently unavailable as you can see from the banner on the top of the page.

**Edit**: The option to show the remaining quota for the month is available again in the subscription page.